# minimizing volume of boundary between partition cells

Tags: combinatorics

If $\Pi$ partitions the set of bit strings of length $n$ into two classes, define the *boundary* of $\Pi$ to be the set of bit strings that are one bit flip away (i.e., Hamming distance one) from a member of the other partition cell.  For a given $n$, how small can the boundary of $\Pi$ be if the two partition cells have to have the same size?